# ios - Adjust one image with @2x and @3x for all iphone screen sizes

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I am developing an app from **iPhone 4s** (3.5 inch screen) to **iPhone 6 Plus** (5.5 inch screen).

I need to adjust one image with @2x and @3x given without scaling images.

As the image width is static and changing it would make it blurry.

How can i achieve this with multiple screen width and height. Is it possible or i have to make different images for all screen sizes?

Comment: You can have a single image for all sizes, the OS will then scale it (it should be the largest image without any @ in the filename) or you can make the three images. It won't be blurry if the image is large enough. If it's not then it'll be scaled up and might be blurry.

Comment: create image in 1x, 2x & 3x resolution and add in project . automatically select image by os

Comment: If you want only one image then, create an image with 3x size directly.  Else you can create an image with 1x, 2x and 3x size.

Comment: follow "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48483934/how-to-handle-iphone-screen-sizes-resolution-for-background-images/48563225#48563225"